# Gimp plugin - batch mode execution

Tags: gimp

Is it possible to execute some plugin in batch mode to modify one picture multiple times? I'd like to use Channel Mixer and execute it with different settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is the BIMP package but I think it is geared more towards running one function against several files.

Otherwise you can script your own, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560). You'll be using:

```
 pdb.plug_in_colors_channel_mixer(image, drawable, monochrome, rr_gain, rg_gain, rb_gain, gr_gain, gg_gain, gb_gain, br_gain, bg_gain, bb_gain)
```

But it will likely be simpler to use ImageMagick's and its [color-matrix operator](/https://imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#color-matrix) from a shell script.